# getDeviceName does not return device name on android

Tags: react-native-device-info

I'm using react-native-device-info to get device name.
But getDeviceName returns unknown in Android.
It's working good in iOS.

version:

- react-native-device-info: 0.25.0,

Any help is much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bluetooth permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH